# SELECT AS OF a version before column drop

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, version, flashback

1/ Does `FLASHBACK` and `SELECT AS OF/ VERSION BETWEEN` use the same *source* of history to fall back to ? This question is related to the second question.

2/ I am aware that `FLASHBACK` cannot go back before a DDL change.

My question is for `SELECT AS OF`, would it be able to select something before a DDL change.
Take for example

```
CREATE TABLE T
(col1 NUMBER, col2 NUMBER)
INSERT INTO T(col1, col2) VALUES('1', '1')
INSERT INTO T(col1, col2) VALUES('2', '2')
COMMIT;
SLEEP(15)
ALTER TABLE T DROP COLUMN col2;
SELECT * FROM T
AS OF SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '10' SECOND;
```

Would the select return 2 columns or 1 ?

Pardon me I do not have a database at hand to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any DDL that alter the structure of a table invalidates any existing undo data for the table. So you will get the error 'ORA-01466' unable to read data - table definition has changed.

Here is a simple test

```
CREATE TABLE T
(col1 NUMBER, col2 NUMBER);
INSERT INTO T(col1, col2) VALUES('1', '1');
INSERT INTO T(col1, col2) VALUES('2', '2');
COMMIT;
SLEEP(15)
ALTER TABLE T DROP COLUMN col2;


SELECT * FROM T
AS OF TIMESTAMP (SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '60' SECOND);
```

`ERRROR ORA-01466` upon executing the above select statement.

However DDL operations that alter the storage attributes of a table do no invalidate undo data so that you can still use flashback query.

Answer (score 1):

1) `FLASHBACK TABLE` and `SELECT .. AS OF` use the same source, UNDO.  There is also `FLASHBACK DATABASE` - although it uses the same mechanism it uses a separate source, flashback logs that must be optionally configured.

2) Flashback table and flashback queries *can* go back before a DDL change if you enable a [flashback archive.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_5009.htm)

To use that feature, add a few statements to the sample code:

```
CREATE FLASHBACK ARCHIVE my_flashback_archive TABLESPACE users RETENTION 10 YEAR;
...
ALTER TABLE t FLASHBACK ARCHIVE my_flashback_archive;
```

Now this statement will return 1 column:

```
SELECT * FROM T;
```

And this statement will return 2 columns:

```
SELECT * FROM T AS OF SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '10' SECOND;
```